# Creating a new database - A user defined stored procedure is getting created automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to create a new database, I am getting a new user defined stored procedure created automatically.

I can't figure out what is going on.

Someone, please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the **name** of that stored procedure? What does it do? Can you look into it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server has a concept of "model" database.  All the elements of the model database are copied into any new database created on the system.

Presumably, your system has a model database with the stored procedure.

You can learn more about the model in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/model-database?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: You were Spoton